# DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL Fails even though I have SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE?

Tags: oracle, permissions, user-roles

I get this error

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-31603: object "XXX" of type TRIGGER not found in schema "YYYY"
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 6069
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 8666
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

when trying to get the sql for triggers using the following sql.

```
SELECT
s.OWNER AS SCHEMA,
s.object_name AS NAME,
dbms_metadata.get_DDL(s.object_type,s.object_name,s.owner) AS "SQL"
FROM SYS.DBA_OBJECTS s
WHERE s.OBJECT_TYPE IN ('TRIGGER')
```

I have the following USER_ROLE_PRIVS: SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE
[USER_ROLE_PRIVS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vzgu.png)

DB VERSION:

```
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
"CORE    12.1.0.2.0    Production"
TNS for IBM/AIX RISC System/6000: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
```

I've tried figure out what is wrong but I have come to a dead end. 
Everywhere I search it says that all I need is SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE unless I am running this inside a procedure. 
I am running the sql through a JDBC connection, however I still get the error even if I am running it using a sql client.

Please let me know if you need to know any other permissions that I have. I already know of the workaround to use DBA_SOURCE, I just need to understand why I can't use get_DDL since  according to the oracle docs I only need to have SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE to be able to use it.

EDIT: A few notes.
This query has been working correctly when scanning other databases I don't know why this is not working on this environment.
I don't want to use DBA_SOURCE since it omits some statements such as 'create trigger' and I want to use the available functions instead of doing manual manipulations. (However if no one can figure out why this is happening I will have to go back to using DBA_SOURCE)
The query has an owner filter I didn't add it here since I wanted to present the problem without any other unnecessary information

Answer (score 0):

How about doing:

```
SELECT
s.OWNER AS SCHEMA,
s.name AS NAME,
s.text as "SQL"
FROM SYS.dba_source s
WHERE s.TYPE IN ('TRIGGER');
```

I would also limit the owner otherwise this could take a long time to execute.

Comment: I don't want to use dba_source since it doesn't give the full sql statement. it omits the create line and I'm not sure if it has any other issues with it as well.   
get_ddl has been working for me all this time without any problems on other databases but there's something missing in this database. I am trying to figure out what the mistake is.   

Yes I am limiting the query based on the owner. I  removed extra filters before posting the issue since it is irrelevant .

Comment: The only thing missing is "CREATE OR REPLACE" which I prefix to the text to get the full source.  Been doing it this way for years and no issues so far.

Comment: Okay thank you, but do you how why this method isn't working?

Comment: No, it works for me. Do you actually have triggers? ora-31603 says *Cause:  The specified object was not found in the database.

Comment: what does this return: select count(*) from dba_objects where object_type='TRIGGER';

Comment: Yes I do have triggers... Why would the rest of the sql run if there are no triggers? There's 'trigger' in the where clause. If there are no triggers there will be no results. Ora 31603 also happens when you don't have rights to access the object not just when the object is not there. This is the issue. According to the documents you only need select catalog role but it looks like I'm missing an extra permission or I have some restriction

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_metada.htm#i1016867

Comment: I've addressed all of those in the original post!

Comment: I cannot replicate the problem, so I can't test.  Sorry!